# PathJS - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'default' (anonymous function)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, path.js

I'm trying to use PathJS, and get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'default'
```

(anonymous function)

I'm using the following tutorial: http://mtrpcic.net/2011/02/fragment-uris-theyre-not-as-bad-as-you-think-really/

With the plugin: https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs

My app loads jQuery then the PathJS plugin, then this code in app.js:

```
$("a").live("click", function(event){
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if(href[0] == "/"){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.hash = "#!" + href;
    }
});

Path.default(function(){
    $.get(window.location.hash.replace("#!", ""), function(data){
        $("#contents").html(data);
    });
});
Path.listen();
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the error?

Comment: Did Josh's solution fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Path.listen()` should be wrapped up like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Path.listen();
)};
```

If you are already doing that ( it doesn't appear so from the code above, but you may have just not included that part ) then I would question your `Path.default` code. I see nothing about a default path in the documentation. There is however, a `Path.root`, but you still need to provide it a route. I'm wondering if that may have been removed from the code at some point, as I do see it mentioned on the tutorial you mentioned.